# What is the Java equivalent of PHP's print_r function?

Tags: java, php, eclipse, variables

I am learning `Java` web development in `Eclipse Kepler` and have retrieved data from a method. The data is held in a `ResultSet` and a `List<Object>` in a `jsp` file.

In `PHP` you can wrap objects in the `print_r()` function to have the structure and contents of it printed out at run-time, is there an equivalent method in Java to do the same thing?

Comment: You would normally use a debugger to see the contents of objects during run time in java.

Comment: If you're doing this for production use, use [`gson`](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) or roll your own. If you're doing it for debugging purposes, as @Kaltiz mentioned, use the debugger. There is no better way than that.

Comment: Agree with using the debugger to output objects. Use breakpoints or after what you need to take a peek at.

Answer (score 0):

I was just asking the same question myself, and while I've found the debugger in Eclipse did it better for me(set a breakpoint, use the variable tab in Debug perspective to view object contents) there are ways to do a print_r equivalent

See this I found: http://en.mytory.net/serverside/2016/01/14/java-print-object-content-like-php-var-dump-or-print-r.html